# How to dismiss a DialogFragment without removing it from FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I want to hide a DialogFragment but also persist the state of all it's views and fields.

I tried using:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
    .hide(dialogFragment)
    .commit();
```

but it works not so well because it will hide the DialogFragment but will not hide the black transparent overlay behind the Dialog which I think is a Dialog Window property.

But then there is no way to show the DialogFragment using the same method because when I try this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
    .show(dialogFragment)
    .commit();
```

it has no effect. The DialogFragment will not show.

Is there any other approach or should I manipulate the Dialog's View ?

Answer (score 2):

Use below to hide your dialog:

```
dialogFragment.getDialog().hide();
```

Use below to reshow your dialog:

```
dialogFragment.getDialog().show();
```

And I suggest you to judge if `dialogFragment.getDialog()` is null or not first when you call `show()` or `hide()`